# Find prime fields over which a polynomial has roots.

Tags: polynomials, modular-arithmetic, roots, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Suppose we have a polynomial

$$h(x) = a_n x^n + \dots + a_1 x + 1$$

Given the values $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, how to determine whether there exists such prime $p$ that $h(x)$ has roots over the field $\mathbb{Z}_p = \mbox{GL}(p)$?

Comment: It depends on the $a_i$. If all $a_i=0$, then there is no root. For $a_1=1$ and $a_i=0$ otherwise there is always a root.

Comment: @Arthur, yes, I could start checking for every prime $p$, but how do I know when to stop? What if it doesn't have roots over any prime $p$?

Comment: Then it doesn'st have roots over any prime $p$. This can happen. Then you are done anyway. What do you really want to know? Can you give any explicit  example of a polynomial?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, the question is, how to determine whether there exists such $p$ that the given polynomial has roots modulo $p$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde My idea was to just check the $p$ possible inputs for any given prime $p$. However, I failed to notice that the question was "how to tell whether there _is_ a $p$ with roots?" If there is a $p$, you can tell within a finite number of checks, but if there is no $p$ where $h$ has roots, checking will never be able to tell you that.

Comment: As I said, the poylnomial $f(x)=1$ certainly has no root over any prime $p$ and this can be checked immediately.  I am not sure what the question expects as an answer.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, it's easy to check for the case $f(x)=1$. How would you check the case $a_i=i^2$ for $i=1,\ldots,100$ for example. Of course, it depends on the $a_i$, the question is how.

Comment: This is very vague to ask "how does it behave on the coefficients $a_i$". I suppose, there is no reasonable nice formula or answer. For your polynomial, say, with $a_i=i^2$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$, we have a root for $p=2,3$, but not for $p=5$, etc.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, well, maybe there are some general methods? For example, if I wanted to write a program that would for the given $a_i$ output prime $p$ and the root $x$, or message that there're no roots over any $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $a_n \ne 0, n\ge 1$, let's choose integer $x_0$ large enough so that $h(x_0)$ is a large integer too. Choose a prime factor p of $h(x_0)$, then $x_0$ is root of h(x) over $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Comment: What if $h(x_0)$ is prime?

Comment: Choose $p=h(x_0)$ in case of it is a prime. As soon as $|h(x_0)|>1$ we could get a prime factor from $h(x_0)$

Comment: Yes, it really is this simple.